# OnFailure() methods throws Exception Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, gson

onFailure in retrofit is throwing this exception "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $" also if i remove setLinient(true) from gson converter the same line 1 coloumn 1 throws one more exception "Malformed json" and this happened all of a sudden previously it was working fine,i'm having a real hard time analyzing what has changed that led to this problem,can someone please have a look at this and help me out,

I have this Json Response coming from server:

```
[{
    "disposal_type_category": {
        "category_entry_total": "21"
    },
    "disposal_types": [{
            "ID": "78",
            "entries": [{
                    "ID": 2584,
                    "entry_tally": "1"
                },
                {
                    "ID": 2578,
                    "entry_tally": "1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ID": "1323",
            "entries": [{
                    "ID": 2583,
                    "entry_tally": "1"
                },
                {
                    "ID": 2579,
                    "entry_tally": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "disposal_type_category": {
        "category_entry_total": "25.2"
    },
    "disposal_types": [{
            "ID": "80",
            "entries": [{
                    "ID": 2583,
                    "entry_tally": "1"
                },
                {
                    "ID": 2579,
                    "entry_tally": "1"
                }

            ]
        },
        {
            "ID": "84",
            "entries": [{
                    "ID": 2583,
                    "entry_tally": "1"
                },
                {
                    "ID": 2579,
                    "entry_tally": "1"
                }

            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

This is my retrofit code:

```
ApiInterface apiService =
            ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    String token = prefs.getString("token", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.

    Call<List<Disposal>> callm = apiService.getCollection(token);
    callm.enqueue(new Callback<List<Disposal>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Disposal>> call, Response<List<Disposal>> response) {
            if (response.body() != null) {
                EntriesList = response.body();
                setRecyclerData(0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Disposal>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

This is in my ApiClient.java:

```
public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

This is in ApiInterface.java:

```
Call<List<Disposal>> getCollection(@Header("Authorization") String token);
```

Disposal.java:

```
public class Disposal {
    @SerializedName("disposal_type_category")
    @Expose
    public DisposalTypeCategory disposalTypeCategory;
    @SerializedName("disposal_types")
    @Expose
    public List<DisposalType> disposalTypes = null;
}
```

DisposalTypeCategory.java:

```
public class DisposalTypeCategory { 
    @serializedname("category_entry_total")
    @expose 
    public String categoryEntryTotal;
}
```

DisposalType.java:

```
public class DisposalType {
    @serializedname("ID")
    @expose 
    public String iD; 
    @serializedname("entries")
    @expose 
    public List<Entries> entries = null;
}
```

Entries.java:

```
public class Entries {
    @serializedname("ID") 
    @expose 
    private int iD;
    @SerializedName("entry_tally")
    @Expose
    private String entryTally;
}
```

I have set setLineant(true) for Gson because if i remove it i will get malformed json exception, even this issue started recently previously was fine, not sure if its related.
The issue started after 2-3 new fields were added to API and the base url was changed but still the core remains same.

Comment: retrofit expect an array and found string

Comment: post the retrofit code here

Comment: Try logging the response, it might be that the api is generating an error instead of the expected json.

Comment: yes but if you see response it is returning array not string thats why i'm confused, i will update the question with retrofit code

Comment: Guys please drop in the reason for downvoting in the comments so that i can correct it thanks

Comment: im wotking in your problem know..wait

Comment: @SiddarthG from the response what data your need to use??

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify DisposalType, Entries   classes like this:

Modify **DisposalType class**

```
public class DisposalType {
    @serializedname("ID")
    @expose 
    public String iD; 

    @serializedname("entries")
    @expose 
    public List<Entries> entries;
}
```

Modify **Entries class**

```
public class Entries {
    @serializedname("ID") 
    @expose 
    private int iD;

 @serializedname("entry_tally") 
    @expose 
    private int entry_tally;

}
```

Comment: Oh thats how it is right now, looks like i missed it while typing in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**This is in ApiInterface.java:**

```
Call<Disposal> getCollection(@Header("Authorization") String token);
```

**This is Your Retrofit Code**

```
ApiInterface apiService =
            ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    String token = prefs.getString("token", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.

Call<Disposal> callm = apiService.getCollection(token);
callm.enqueue(new Callback<Disposal>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Disposal> call, Response<Disposal> response) {
        if (response.body() != null) {
            Disposal = response.body();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Disposal> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```